# Metadata for a paper in the generative framework?

Tags: research, standards, metadata

sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, but I don't know who to turn to. I'm trying to publish a paper on Gapping in a small national journal - they publish anything related to language and literature. I sent the paper and they said that they need me to write the metadata for the paper. Among other things they want me to describe the research sample characteristics (e.g. linguistic corpus). Obviously, most of my examples are invented (or adapted from other authors) for that specific circumstance, just like most papers in the generative framework. What should I write?

It's clear that they don't publish many papers in generative grammar. They also want me to write Geo-spatial coverage and chronological coverage, which I feel I should just write n./a. to. Thoughts?

Comment: Do they ask for keywords or metadata? Metadata are not "visible" for the user.

Comment: Metadata. Keywords count as a part of metadata according to the "metadata form" they sent me. But there's also these other things I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

The names for the metadata fields that you drop sound like [Dublin Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core) and the linked Wikipedia article has some explanation and further links. Note that Dublin Core metatada fields can occur in any multiplicity in your description, including 0—every metadata field is optional.

Fill as many metadata fields as you can, and don't hesitate to use some of them (e.g., subject) more than once. The metdata make your paper findable for later users using, e.g., facetted search.

For the concrete question about coverage: I don't know your paper, but it is probably about present day English where you have a geographical coverage of the main anglophone countries unless you are specific about British or American English and a temporal coverage of say 1949/2019 (last 70 years).

Comment: Thank you. I examine the phenomenon of gapping in multiple languages, not just English, so I'll write Europe and Asia. But my main question is mostly what to write about "research sample characteristics" since, again, the examples are not from a corpus, they are invented examples made to illustrate the "grammaticalness" of certain forms. Is there a common word/phrase for this type of sample?

Comment: I am not aware of a common word or phrase for that kind of example sentences, so you are free to use *invented examples made to illustrate grammaticalness* or some similar formulation of your own.

Comment: "Grammatical and ungrammatical utterance examples from many languages involving Gapping"